# Android SDK Add-On hidden class

Tags: android, sdk, android-5.0-lollipop, add-on, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I need to export a hidden class through a SDK Add-On in Android Lollipop. I'm able to export non-hidden classes. After unsuccessfully trying the "usual way" I thought the problem was due to the @hide tag. So I decided to try the "dirty" way of getting rid of the @hide keyword responsible to hide the class (even if that would obviously break compatibility with the standard API). After removing the @hide keyword and building the class with #include(BUILD_JAVA_LIBRARY) in Android.mk, the Java library Jar file is empty. So I have two questions:

1. Why the Jar file is empty even if the DEX file includes the class?
2. How do I achieve the same result without removing the @hide keyword?

Thank you.

Note: I have used these resources as references/documentation: http://elinux.org/images/5/5c/Build_and_Distributing_SDK_Add-Ons.pdf
https://newcircle.com/s/post/1571/exploring_sdk_add_ons_for_android_devices_larry_schiefer_video

Comment: I'm not sure that the @hide keyword plays a role in what I'm trying to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution by myself and it doesn't really involve the @hide tag. So I restored the @hide tag. The @hide tag is meaningful only when building the standard SDK. Then, I have replaced the package qualified class name, "+package_name.class_name" to export with something like "+package_name.*" into the Add-On defs file. After cleaning and rebuilding the Add-On has all the exported classes.